# Is there a way to visually display a linked list in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I am extremely new to coding.

I am writing a task manager application. I have a taskWindow object (containing a taskName, taskDescription, confidence, etc.) which is saved to a text file. I also have a main dashboard.
I wanted to know if there is a way to visually show the information from the object in the main dashboard main class.
I was thinking that I had to somehow extract the information from the file in order to then display it onto the main dashboard but since I am pretty new to coding I have no idea if this is even possible.

This is the code for the **save** button:

```
 private void SaveTaskButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

    //Code for save button to write TaskWindow variables into a file

    taskName = TaskNameTextField.getText();
    taskDescription = TaskDescriptionTextArea.getText();
    confidence =  (int) ConfidenceSpinner.getValue();
    priority = (int) PrioritySpinner.getValue();
    reminder = (boolean) RemindedCheckBox.isSelected();

    try {

        FileWriter writer;
        writer = new FileWriter("SentientCalendar.txt", true);
        writer.write(taskName);
        writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        writer.write(taskDescription);
        writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        writer.write("" + confidence);
        writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        writer.write("" + priority);
        writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        writer.write(reminder + "");
        writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        writer.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Saved");

    } catch (HeadlessException | IOException e){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (rootPane, "Error");
    }

}
```